# How to generate two gridviews on SINGLE DATE CLICK

Tags: date, gridview

Is it possible to generate two gridviews on SINGLE DATE CLICK.If yes then how?

Comment: @nidhi where is your date present which would be clicked to get the gridviews populated.

Comment: Which language you are using, please post some more details so that somebody can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET.
Add to gridviews two your page set both their attributes visible="false"
in the codebehind event handler for date click, populate the gridviews by setting their Datasource, call their databind methods and set their attributes visible = true.

Comment: thnkx for your response but is it possible to have same member called 'Calendar1_SelectionChanged' with the same parameter types.

Comment: @vinay i am using calendar control

Comment: you do only have one calendar control.
In that control's Calendar1_SelectionChanged event you set data source for the two gridviews and make them visible.